# Get a top-end part of the line

Tags: regex, perl

There is an example line:

'Hour |Day |Year'

I need to get part of as year, but I can not for example with the decision:

```
$string = 'Hour |Day |Year';
$string =~ s/^.*?|([^|]+)$/$1/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this....

```
$string = 'Hour |Day |Year';
$string =~ s/^(?:.*?)\|([^|]+)$/$1/m;
```

Comment: You didn't even need the anchors (nor the `m` modifier). `s/.*\|([^|]+)/$1/` would do.

Comment: TMTOWTDI, of course. My favorite is `($_)=(/([^|]+)$/) for $string`.

Answer (score 3):

Split the string into elements:

```
my @elements = split( /\|/, $string );
```

And then get last element:

```
print $elements[-1];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need a solution only through a regular expression :)

Comment: @BetarU - why? (and you didn't specify that in the question)

Comment: Well, I wanted to understand why the regular expression does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, you just need to "escape" the first `|`:

```
$string = 'Hour |Day |Year';
$string =~ s/^.*?\|([^|]+)$/$1/;
```

because it is a special character that means `or` in Perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one:

```
([^|]+$)
```

It will just pick up the `Year` part from the end. No need to match the entire string.

#### [Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/4xmv3xQFKZ)

Your code should look like:

```
$string = 'Hour |Day |Year';
$string =~ s/([^|]+$)/$1/;
```

Comment: Have you seen this regex ?